# Adding a property for the count of associated entities in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, wcf-ria-services

I'm using Code First to write my data layer, then transmitting to a Silverlight front end using RIA services.  Since I have to serialize everything, I would like to get some additional information on each entity before sending it across the wire (to reduce load time).  In the past I have done this by translating everything to a POCO class that has the additional information.  I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this.  To give you an idea, here's my class:

```
public class District
{
    // ... Other properties, not important
    public ICollection Installations { get; set; }

    //The property I would like to calculate on the fly
    [NotMapped]
    public int InstallationCount { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to have this property calculate automatically before I send it across the wire?  One option would be just to Include the Installation collection, but that adds a lot of bulk (there are about 50 properties on the Installation entity, and potentially hundreds of records per district).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than making InstallationCount an automatic property, just use the get to return the count function of Installations collection.

```
public class District
{
    public virtual ICollection<Installation> Installations { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int InstallationCount { get { return Installations.Count; } }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this before.  That code will be executed client side, so it doesn't work if you haven't included the collection of entities.

Comment: Indeed the function that tried to get District has to .Include("Installation") for this to work. Any other ideas?